# Paypal Rounding up Amount intentionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using .NET PayPal API, I am creating a payment and I need to round up/down my invoice total based on specific rounding value amount. But PayPal keeps checking if:

1. `subtotal = sum of items' line total`
2. `total = subtotal + tax`

I need the proper way to tell PayPal that I know there is differences in values and I am doing this on purpose which means:

```
total = subtotal + tax + roundingValue
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: I am using Paypal API for payments against SAP Business One Invoice document. SAP makes specific rounding depending on different factors.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: Can you clarify? Unsure what you're saying. End of day, you're doing whatever calculations (special rounding etc) you want _before_ sending over the data to Paypal - obviously [the totals should _add_ up correctly](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx.cs#L63)

Comment: I am paying against invoice in Switzerland. As customer requested earlier, I have to round the total amount's cents (centimes) either to 0(0,10,20..etc) or 5 (5,15,25..etc). Example: 10.13 => 10.15
10,11 => 10,00

Comment: As above you'll have to do that _before_ sending the amount to Paypal. You may need to _skip_ providing an [`ItemList`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx.cs#L29) in your [`Transaction`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-transaction) and [`Details`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx.cs#L63) in [`Amount`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-amount) and only provide your _pre-calculated_ total for payment. Hth

Comment: thanks @EdSF, that was good solution